# Using Examine Manager to search content

Tags: c#, lucene, umbraco, examine

This is the first time I have used Examine - So far this is working, `results` variable have the correct data, however what I want to do is add the `searchTerm` variable I want to search all fields of all nodes that currently are returned in `results`

Any Ideas? - Thanks in advance.

```
var searchEngine = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ExternalSearcher"];
var criteria = searchEngine.CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.Or);

IBooleanOperation query = criteria.NodeTypeAlias("level1")
.Or().NodeTypeAlias("level2")
.Or().NodeTypeAlias("simpleTextPage")
.Or().NodeTypeAlias("contactPage")
.Or().NodeTypeAlias("Locationfinder");

string searchTerm = "Term to Search for here";

var results = searchEngine.Search(query.Compile());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer. Firstly you need to specify which field(s) you wish to search against:

`.Or().Field("bodyText", searchTerm)`

This makes the assumption that your pages have a `bodyText` property. You can append additional fields onto this to search against other properties, e.g. name, introText etc.

Secondly, if you want to search across *all* fields, you will need to create a field that contains all the text content from the page being indexed. You need to:

1. Create an Umbraco event that implements `IApplicationEventHandler`;
2. Add a handler for gathering node data:

   ```
   void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase app, ApplicationContext ctx)
   {
       ExamineManager.Instance
                     .IndexProviderCollection["ExternalIndexer"]
                     .GatheringNodeData += OnGatheringNodeData;
   }
   ```
3. Create your combined field:

   ```
   protected void OnGatheringNodeData(object sender, IndexingNodeDataEventArgs e)
   {
       var builder = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var entry in e.Fields)
       {
           builder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", entry.Value);
       }

       e.Fields.Add("combinedText", builder.ToString());
   }
   ```

   4. Change your search to be `.Or().Field("combinedText", searchTerm)`;

Now each time a page is published, it will combine all fields into one so that they can be search upon in the way you wish.

However, personally, I would advise you select specific fields to combine as there is rarely any need to combine all. This is usually a sign that there is little consistency in your document types. I always use common aliases throughout all my doc types for reasons like this, e.g. bodyText, introText, summaryText etc. This way if needed I could filter out the fields ending in "Text" or have my aliases as static strings.